# Can I connect a bathroom sink drain to a bathtub drain?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathtub, renovation

I am looking to move the bathroom sink across the bathroom. The only possibility of draining it would be by tying it to the adjacent bathtub / shower combo floor drain.

My question is whether this is allowed or not. I do not have access to the floor below.

Comment: You really need to tell us more about your plumbing type and arrangement. A diagram would help, or a clear and concise description.

Comment: Where are you connecting if you don’t have access? Someone on here has a avatar of a sink draining into a toilet (dmoore?) so I had to ask.

Comment: @EdBeal - sinks can drain into toilet according to updated HPC 2020 Article 1.1.1  - no number 2.